# How do i select a button from a table that has identical identifying selectors?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to automate signing in on a page where there are two login buttons.

[image]

I'm still new with coding in general, but i read that `xpath` is the way to go.

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='submit' and @value='Login']".click()
```

However, this defaults to the first login button. What selector should I use to select the second button?

This is the the code for the html:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: You could try `find_elements_by_xpath` that's elements with the s. It will return a list if there are two identified by that same xapth. Then you can check if the list has two elements. If it does you can just do `find_elements_by_xpath(...)[-1].click()` to get the last element

Answer (score 0):

If the element more than one, you can use count `[]` at the end locator like this:

```
(//input[@type='submit' and @value='Login'])[2]
```

This is for second element:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("(//input[@type='submit' and @value='Login'])[2]").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Many ways you can do that.Since you are selecting last button.You can use index like `(//input[@value='Login'])[last()]`

**Option 1:**

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("(//input[@value='Login'])[last()]").click()
```

**Option 2**

You can take the reference of table cell and xpath would be.

```
//td[@id='domainlogin_domain_selection']/following::td[1]/input[@value='Login']
```

So to click on the button.

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@id='domainlogin_domain_selection']/following::td[1]/input[@value='Login']").click()
```

To handle dynamic element use `WebDriverWait` and `element_to_be_clickable`

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//td[@id='domainlogin_domain_selection']/following::td[1]/input[@value='Login']"))).click()
```

OR

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"(//input[@value='Login'])[last()]"))).click()
```

Note : You need to import followings when you use WebDriverWait.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a css attribute = value selector with * contains operator to target the element by its `onclick` attribute. Nice and concise and easy to read

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("[onclick*=domainlogin]").click()
```

Reference:

1. [Attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code in order to click second login Button

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("(//input[@value='Login'])[last()]").click()
```

or

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@id='domainlogin_domain_selection']/following::td[1]/input[@value='Login']").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

The buttons have different values of the [`onclick` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) so you can use the following selectors assuming using XPath [contains()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) function:

1. First button:

   ```
   //input[@type='submit' and @value='Login' and contains(@onclick, 'userLogin')]
   ```
2. Second button:

   ```
   //input[@type='submit' and @value='Login' and contains(@onclick, 'domainLogin')]
   ```

References:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)